# Pass new php array key into json

Tags: php, json

I have 2 table users(id,userid,fn,ln) and userdetails(id,userid,image,history,location,activity)
And i have written a query for first table to retrieve all the data and i want only history and location ,from second table.

i have retrieved the array and i am sending it to json_encode.
Now i want to retrieve the history,location and create a new key History and i want to add history location values to history key.

I need a query and json format for these.

- For particular user i need to retrieve is own history
  In both tables user id in common
  Thanks in advance

  $sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth);
      $i=0;
      foreach($result as $data) { 
          $final_array[$i]['id'] = $data['id'];
          $final_array[$i]['email'] = $data['email'];
          $final_array[$i]['fname'] = $data['fname'];
          $final_array[$i]['lname'] = $data['lname'];

  ```
      $sth2 = mysql_query("SELECT id,places,act FROM user_dates WHERE user_id= '".$data['email']."'");
      $result2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth2);
      $j=0;
      $history_array = array();
      foreach($result2 as $data2) { 
        $history_array[$j] = array("id" => $data2['id'],"places" => $data2['places'], "act " => $data2['act ']);
        $j++;
      }
      $final_array[$i]['history'] = $history_array;


      $i++;
  } 
  echo json_encode($final_array);
  ```

[
    {
        "id": "81",
        "user_id": "2011",
        "fn": "asd.",
        "ln": "wer",
        "History": [
            {
                "id": "350",
                "history": "make1",
                "Location": "qwe"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "82",
        "user_id": "2012",
        "fn": "asd1",
        "ln": "wer1",
        "History": [
            {
                "id": "350",
                "history": "make2",
                "Location": "qwe2"
            }
        ]
    }
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Userdetails` table contains `multiple records` per user. So you need to do sub query and get the results and then form a `mulch-dimensional array`. Finally, `encode as a JSON`.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();

$i=0;
foreach($result as $data) { 
    $final_array[$i]['id'] = $data['id'];
    $final_array[$i]['userid'] = $data['userid'];
    $final_array[$i]['fn'] = $data['fn'];
    $final_array[$i]['ln'] = $data['ln'];

    $sth2 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT location,activity FROM userdetails WHERE userid= ".$data['id']."");
    $sth2->execute();
    $result2 = $sth2->fetchAll();
    $j=0;
    $history_array = array();
    foreach($result2 as $data2) { 
      $history_array[$j] = array("location" => $data2['location'], "activity " => $data2['activity ']);
      $j++;
    }
    $final_array[$i]['history'] = $history_array;


    $i++;
} 
echo json_encode($final_array);
```

Comment: Suppose if i want to fetch all data from table1 ie., users and only   history and activity from second table2 ie., user details

Comment: you can simply add "select users.*, , userdetails.history, , userdetails.activity"

Comment: for history i have missing square brackets "History": [ { "id": "350", "history": "make1", "Location": "qwe" } ] as i shown above what can be done for these

Comment: $final_array[$i]['history'] = array(array("id" => $data['userDetailsId'], "history" => $data['history'], , "Location" => $data['Location']));

Comment: The query is running depend on 2 table if i want 2 run a query depend on 1 table For example: i have only two users for that 2 users there will be to n number of histories stored in table 2 ,i need only 2 rows in the output all history should be inside particular row of the user. can u tell me what solves my problem please

Comment: Check if your second query where condition would be $data['userid'] instead of $data['id'] ..Also, check if both tables are related to that "userid"

Comment: now it is missing with the $final_array[$i]['id'] = $data['id']; is not matching with query id The id is something like this 6904053918, it is showing only single digit number

Comment: I m not getting..please post your both tables with some values..as well post your code what you did so far..so that I can help you in a better way

Comment: i have added the code what i have done those are my table column names.

Comment: Second query param value is not valid...email should be changed to user Id ..and then check pls

Comment: i have given the param as email in table1 and in table2 as user_id

Comment: echo the second query and execute in phpmyadmin and see if any records there for any user?

Comment: When i am using foreach,from the database it is showing only first character of the value  Eg:if userid number is 98009890 then it is showing only 9 I tried while loop now working. But Thanx bro